# C, format file for data of HTTP response

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have no experience with `fscanf()` and very little with functions for `FILE`. I have code that correctly determines if a client requested an existing file (using `stat()` and it also ensures it is not a directory). I will omit this part because it is working fine.

My goal is to send a string back to the client with a HTTP header (a string) and the correctly read data, which I would imagine has to become a string at some point to be concatenated with the header for sending back. I know that `+` is not valid C, but for simplicity I would like to send this: `headerString+dataString`.

The code below does seem to work for text files but not images. I was hoping that reading each character individually would solve the problem but it does not. When I point a browser (Firefox) at my server looking for an image it tells me "The image (the name of the image) cannot be displayed because it contains errors.".

This is the code that is supposed to read a file into `httpData`:

```
int i = 0;
FILE* file;
file = fopen(fullPath, "r");
if (file == NULL) errorMessageExit("Failed to open file");
while(!feof(file)) {
    fscanf(file, "%c", &httpData[i]);
    i++;
}
fclose(file);
printf("httpData = %s\n", httpData);
```

**Edit**: This is what I send:

```
char* httpResponse = malloc((strlen(httpHeader)+strlen(httpData)+1)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(httpResponse, httpHeader);
strcat(httpResponse, httpData);
printf("HTTP response = %s\n", httpResponse);
```

The data part produces ???? for the image but correct html for an html file.

Comment: To read a binary file you need: `file = fopen(fullPath, "rb");`

Comment: I just tried it (and updated above), the image produces ????

Comment: You need to worry about null bytes in the data; the `%s` format will stop at the first one.  You should be using `while (fscanf(file, "%c", &httpData[i]) == 1) i++;` (using `feof()` in a loop is almost always a bug — and is specifically a bug when you don't check the return from `fscanf()` as in the code you show).  You need to think about CRLF line endings; HTTP requires them for text files.  You can't use `strcpy()` for the data; you'll need to use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, could you please post the two parts of your comment as an answer. I think I understand the first part but I don't know how to go about using the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images contain binary data.  Any of the 256 distinct 8-bit patterns may appear in the image including, in particular, the null byte, 0x00 or `'\0'`.  On some systems (notably Windows), you need to distinguish between text files and binary files, using the letter `b` in the standard I/O `fopen()` call (works fine on Unix as well as Windows).  Given that binary data can contain null bytes, you can't use `strcpy()` et al to copy chunks of data around since the `str*()` functions stop copying at the first null byte.  Therefore, you have to use the `mem*()` functions which take a start position and a length, or an equivalent.

Applied to your code, printing the binary `httpData` with `%s` won't work properly; the `%s` will stop at the first null byte.  Since you have used `stat()` to verify the existence of the file, you also have a size for the file.  Assuming you don't have to deal with dynamically changing files, that means you can allocate `httpData` to be the correct size.  You can also pass the size to the reading code.  This also means that the reading code can use `fread()` and the writing code can use `fwrite()`, saving on character-by-character I/O.

Thus, we might have a function:

```
int readHTTPData(const char *filename, size_t size, char *httpData)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    size_t n;
    if (fp == 0)
        return E_FILEOPEN;
    n = fread(httpData, size, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    if (n != 1)
        return E_SHORTREAD;
    fputs("httpData = ", stdout);
    fwrite(httpData, size, 1, stdout);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The function returns 0 on success, and some predefined (negative?) error numbers on failure.  Since memory allocation is done before the routine is called, it is pretty simple:

- Open the file; report error if that fails.
- Read the file in a single operation.
- Close the file.
- Report error if the read did not get all the data that was expected.
- Report on the data that was read (debugging only — and printing binary data to standard output raw is not the best idea in the world, but it parallels what the code in the question does).
- Report on success.

In the original code, there is a loop:

```
int i = 0;
...
while(!feof(file)) {
    fscanf(file, "%c", &httpData[i]);
    i++;
}
```

This loop has a lot of problems:

1. You should not use `feof()` to test whether there is more data to read. It reports whether an EOF indication *has* been given, not whether it *will* be given.
2. Consequently, when the last character has been read, the `feof()` reports 'false', but the `fscanf()` tries to read the next (non-existent) character, adds it to the buffer (probably as a letter such as ÿ, y-umlaut, 0xFF, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS).
3. The code makes no check on how many characters have been read, so it has no protection against buffer overflow.
4. Using `fscanf()` to read a single character is a lot of overhead compared to `getc()`.

Here's a more nearly correct version of the code, assuming that `size` is the number of bytes allocated to `httpData`.

```
int i = 0;
int c;

while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF && i < size)
    httpData[i++] = c;
```

You could check that you get EOF when you expect it.  Note that the `fread()` code does the size checking inside the `fread()` function.  Also, the way I wrote the arguments, it is an all-or-nothing proposition — either all `size` bytes are read or everything is treated as missing.  If you want byte counts and are willing to tolerate or handle short reads, you can reverse the order of the size arguments. You could also check the return from `fwrite()` if you wanted to be sure it was all written, but people tend to be less careful about checking that output succeeded.  (It is almost always crucial to check that you got the input you expected, though — don't skimp on input checking.)

At some point, for plain text data, you need to think about CRLF vs NL line endings.  Text files handle that automatically; binary files do not.  If the data to be transferred is `image/png` or something similar, you probably don't need to worry about this.  If you're on Unix and dealing with `text/plain`, you may have to worry about CRLF line endings (but I'm not an expert on this — I've not done low-level HTTP stuff recently (not in this millennium), so the rules may have changed).